# Bootstrap 3 carousel and navbar not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have written some code and after I ran it, it got these problems which I am not sure how to fix:

First problem: The navbar's dropdown menu doesn't expand.

Second problem: The li items do not have their proper names in there.

Third problem: The carousel is not working at all (it doesn't switch the pictures automatically or manually, or using the arrows, or occupy the full width of the screen are just the problems I saw, but there might be more). My code is below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">
<head>
    <title>Bootstrap website</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="icon" href="" />

    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport", content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
</head>
<body id="body">
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS & JS -->
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Title</a>
            </div>

            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse ">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                </ul>
                <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
                </form>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div class="navbar-collapse"><!-- /. -->
        </div>
    </nav>
    <div id="carousel-example" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#carousel-example" data-slide-to="0" class=""></li>
            <li data-target="#carousel-example" data-slide-to="1" class=""></li>
            <li data-target="#carousel-example" data-slide-to="2" class="active"></li>
        </ol>
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="item">
                <img data-src="holder.js/900x500/auto/#777:#7a7a7a/text:First slide" alt="First slide" src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHdpZHRoPSI5MDAiIGhlaWdodD0iNTAwIj48cmVjdCB3aWR0aD0iOTAwIiBoZWlnaHQ9IjUwMCIgZmlsbD0iIzc3NyI+PC9yZWN0Pjx0ZXh0IHRleHQtYW5jaG9yPSJtaWRkbGUiIHg9IjQ1MCIgeT0iMjUwIiBzdHlsZT0iZmlsbDojN2E3YTdhO2ZvbnQtd2VpZ2h0OmJvbGQ7Zm9udC1zaXplOjU2cHg7Zm9udC1mYW1pbHk6QXJpYWwsSGVsdmV0aWNhLHNhbnMtc2VyaWY7ZG9taW5hbnQtYmFzZWxpbmU6Y2VudHJhbCI+Rmlyc3Qgc2xpZGU8L3RleHQ+PC9zdmc+">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        <h1>Example headline.</h1>
                        <p>Note: If you're viewing this page via a <code>file://</code> URL, the "next" and "previous" Glyphicon buttons on the left and right might not load/display properly due to web browser security rules.</p>
                        <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Sign up today</a></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <img data-src="holder.js/900x500/auto/#666:#6a6a6a/text:Second slide" alt="Second slide" src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHdpZHRoPSI5MDAiIGhlaWdodD0iNTAwIj48cmVjdCB3aWR0aD0iOTAwIiBoZWlnaHQ9IjUwMCIgZmlsbD0iIzY2NiI+PC9yZWN0Pjx0ZXh0IHRleHQtYW5jaG9yPSJtaWRkbGUiIHg9IjQ1MCIgeT0iMjUwIiBzdHlsZT0iZmlsbDojNmE2YTZhO2ZvbnQtd2VpZ2h0OmJvbGQ7Zm9udC1zaXplOjU2cHg7Zm9udC1mYW1pbHk6QXJpYWwsSGVsdmV0aWNhLHNhbnMtc2VyaWY7ZG9taW5hbnQtYmFzZWxpbmU6Y2VudHJhbCI+U2Vjb25kIHNsaWRlPC90ZXh0Pjwvc3ZnPg==">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        <h1>Another example headline.</h1>
                        <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
                        <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Learn more</a></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item active">
                <img data-src="holder.js/900x500/auto/#555:#5a5a5a/text:Third slide" alt="Third slide" src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHdpZHRoPSI5MDAiIGhlaWdodD0iNTAwIj48cmVjdCB3aWR0aD0iOTAwIiBoZWlnaHQ9IjUwMCIgZmlsbD0iIzU1NSI+PC9yZWN0Pjx0ZXh0IHRleHQtYW5jaG9yPSJtaWRkbGUiIHg9IjQ1MCIgeT0iMjUwIiBzdHlsZT0iZmlsbDojNWE1YTVhO2ZvbnQtd2VpZ2h0OmJvbGQ7Zm9udC1zaXplOjU2cHg7Zm9udC1mYW1pbHk6QXJpYWwsSGVsdmV0aWNhLHNhbnMtc2VyaWY7ZG9taW5hbnQtYmFzZWxpbmU6Y2VudHJhbCI+VGhpcmQgc2xpZGU8L3RleHQ+PC9zdmc+">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        <h1>One more for good measure.</h1>
                        <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
                        <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Browse gallery</a></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example" data-slide="prev"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span></a>
        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example" data-slide="next"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></a>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your code working correctly. I think you should check if your network connection to CDN work or not. (Hit `F12` then error (if any) will show in console)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to include an older jquery cdn for your code

Remove the jquery cdn you are using at start of body tag and use this right before end of 'body tag':

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS & JS -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>
</html>
```